# how to split a const char*?

Tags: c++, char, constants, cut

i have

```
const char* hour = "Wed Mar 23 18:10:57 2016";
```

I would like to cut "18:10:57" in another new const char*

Comment: Don't use `const char*`. Cut suggests removal, which `const` doesn't really allow.

Comment: I need to use const char* because a sdl function need that..

Comment: Use `std::string` until you need the parameter, then create a `const char*` from the `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks ! it works :)

Comment: Be sure not to use a shallow copy of the object.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the `std::strtok()` function. There is a reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

You will need to copy your original data into a temporary area that does not have the `const` attribute. `std::strtok()` will split your string up according to the delimiter you specify, in this case a single blank character.

Each successive call to `std::strtok()` will advance a pointer to the next token in the string.

Comment: You can't use stroke on a constant string.  It modifies the original.

Comment: @CrazyEddie That's why my answer included the sentence "You will need to copy your original data into a temporary area that does not have the 'const' attribute."